# Ubuntu 14.10 MAAS - Importing images

Tags: 14.10, maas

Hello I've tried to run the command to import images to ubuntu maas however I get an error and the web config page doesn't seem to import them either.

The server does have a network connection as I was able to run the `apt-get update` command.

`~$ maas-import-pxe-files
usage: maas-import-pxe-files [-h] --sources-file SOURCES_FILE
maas-import-pxe-files: error: argument --sources-file is required`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In 14.10 MAAS now handles the importing of boot images. You know longer need to run that script. On the new "Images" page you can start the import process.

You can also do this from the command line. Once you have logged in using the command line. [Documentation for logging over the command line is here].[1](http://maas.ubuntu.com/docs/maascli.html#api-key)

maas  boot-resources import

You can then monitor the progress of importing with.

maas  boot-resources read